# Change the labels of plotcluster() in R

Tags: r, plot, label, cluster-computing, visualization

I am trying to label the data points in the plot below, is there any parameter that controls the labels in `plotcluster()`? Ideally, I would like to have as label the row name of each datapoint instead of the number of its cluster, and keep the color to separate clusters.

[image: plotcluster visualization]

I am using this code to produce the plot, where seedsSD is a matrix and myKmeans3$cluster is the cluster each point is assigned to.

```
plotcluster(seedsSD, myKmeans3$cluster)
```